# aws ec2 Permission denied (publickey) in the bitnami server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I'm having the server with bitnami user and able to login to the server successfully. As a requirement created new sub users. But, I'm getting an error as **Permission denied (publickey)**.

1. Created new user as xyz.
2. Created new directory under /home/xyz/.ssh
3. Added my public key

Later getting an error as **Permission denied (publickey)**

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. Could you please confirm you created the the /home/xyz/.ssh/authorized_keys file with your public key inside and set its permissions correctly `sudo chown xyz:xyz /home/xyz/.ssh && sudo chmod 600 /home/xyz/.ssh/authorized_keys`?

Comment: Yes, I have set the same permission levels @JotaMartos

Comment: Directory permissions __drwxr-xr-x  2 phani admin 4096 Apr 20 05:43 .ssh/__
Public key permissions __-rw------- 1 phani admin  755 Apr 20 05:43 authorized_keys__

Comment: I am confused by your `chown` example of `xyz`, but your directory listing shows `phani` as the owner of the directory, and your name is `Phani`. It looks like the `.ssh` directory is owned by the wrong user?

Comment: I have used xyz. But i'm looking for phani user permissions. And phani user is under admin group. @JohnRotenstein

Comment: [Add New User Accounts with SSH Access to an Amazon EC2 Linux Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/new-user-accounts-linux-instance/)

Comment: Yes @JohnRotenstein, Created user with same permissions as mentioned above. In all Ubuntu servers it's working fine. But, facing this issue in the bitnami server.

Comment: I just followed the guide in a Bitnami instance and it worked fine for me. Please ensure you copy the correct public key in the .ssh/authorized_keys file to be able to access the instance using SSH. You can check that the user is created properly by running the `sudo su - xyz` command.

Comment: Hi @JotaMartos, I'm using the same key and it's working fine in the other ubuntu machines. But, i'm facing only issue in bitnami server.